# Reload Div on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a MVC view that has bootstrap navtabs in it. On each tab a different view loads.  They are called delayed spiff, and instantspiff. I have added a datepicker and a button that should display data in the 2 views. The only problem is that when I click my button the views don't refresh. They keep their original data instead of the new data based on the date.  I need to somehow reload the view after the date is selected and then show the new data.  I'll share some of my code.  Here's my code:

Main view:

```
<div class="container-fluid delayed_spiff_main">


<div class="row-fluid 1">
    <div class="col-lg-12 delayed_spiff_body">

        <div class="row spiff-datepicksection">
            <div class="col-lg-6 pull-right">
                <div class="col-sm-5 col-lg-offset-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group date">
                            <input type="text" id="startDate" class="form-control" />
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <input class="spiffdate-btn" type="button" value="Submit" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row spiff_tabs_body">
            <!-- Nav tabs -->

            <ul class="nav nav-tabs spiff_tabs" role="tablist">
                <li role="presentation" class="active">
                    <a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-id="delayedspiff" data-toggle="tab" onclick="FormGet('dashboard/delayedspiff', 'delayedspiff')">Potential Spiff</a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation">
                    <a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-id="instantspiff" data-toggle="tab" onclick="FormGet('dashboard/instantspiff', 'delayedspiff')">Instant Spiff</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- Tab panes -->
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="delayedspiff"></div>
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="instantspiff"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(function () {
    FormGet('dashboard/delayedspiff', 'delayedspiff');
});
</script>
```

javascript to load details in view:

```
function pullDetails(carrierId, startDate, status, divid) {

    $.get("@Url.Action("getDelayedSpiffOrderDetails", "Dashboard")",
        { carrierId: carrierId, startDate: startDate, status: status },
        function (data) {
            $('.' + divid + ' .submitted_details').html(data);
            $('.' + divid).removeClass('carrier-hide');

        });

}
```

And just to make this even more confusing here is my Controller code:

```
public ActionResult DelayedSpiff(DateTime? startDate)
    {
        var available = _appService.GetFeatureStatus(1, "spiffDashboard");
        if (!available)
            return RedirectToAction("DatabaseDown", "Error", new { area = "" });

        //var startDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-6);

        if (!startDate.HasValue || startDate.Value == DateTime.MinValue)
        {
            startDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7);
        }
        else
        {
            startDate = startDate.Value.AddDays(-7);                
        }           

        var acctId = User.AccountID;

        var endDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1); // 1

        Dictionary<DateTime, List<SpiffSummaryModel>> dict = new Dictionary<DateTime,List<SpiffSummaryModel>>();

        try
        {
            var properties = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "Type", "DelayedSpiff" }
            };
            telemetry.TrackEvent("Dashboard", properties);

            dict = _reportingService.GetDailyDelayedSpiffSummaries(acctId, startDate.Value, endDate);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (e.InnerException is SqlException && e.InnerException.Message.StartsWith("Timeout expired"))
            {
                throw new TimeoutException("Database connection timeout");
            }
            var error = _errorCodeMethods.GetErrorModelByTcError(PROJID.ToString("000") + PROCID.ToString("00") + "001", "Exception Getting DelayedSpiff Dashboard View", PROJID, PROCID);
            error.ErrorTrace = e.ToString();
            _errorLogMethods.LogError(error);
            return RedirectToAction("index", "error", new { error = error.MaskMessage });
        }

        var spiffDateModels = new List<DelayedSpiffDateModel>();

        foreach (var entry in dict)
        {
            var spiffDateModel = new DelayedSpiffDateModel();

            spiffDateModel.Date = entry.Key;

            spiffDateModel.Carriers = new List<DelayedSpiffCarrierModel>();

            foreach (var item in entry.Value)
            {
                var spiffCarrierModel = new DelayedSpiffCarrierModel();
                spiffCarrierModel.Carrier = item.CarrierName;
                spiffCarrierModel.CarrierId = item.CarrierId;
                spiffCarrierModel.ApprovedSpiffTotal = item.ApprovedSpiffTotal;
                spiffCarrierModel.EligibleActivationCount = item.EligibleActivationCount;
                spiffCarrierModel.IneligibleActivationCount = item.IneligibleActivationCount;
                spiffCarrierModel.PotentialSpiffTotal = item.PotentialSpiffTotal;
                spiffCarrierModel.SubmittedActivationCount = item.SubmittedActivationCount;
                spiffCarrierModel.UnpaidSpiffTotal = item.UnpaidSpiffTotal;
                spiffDateModel.Carriers.Add(spiffCarrierModel);
            }

            spiffDateModels.Add(spiffDateModel);
        }
        spiffDateModels = spiffDateModels.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).ToList();

        return PartialView(spiffDateModels);
    }
```

UPDATE code that loads inside of tabpanel:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-11 col-center-block delayspiffdata" id="details">



        <table class="delay_spiff_tbl">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="blank"></th>
                    <th>Submitted Activations / Potential Spiff</th>
                    <th>Approved Activations / Approved Spiff</th>
                    <th>Ineligible Activations / Unpaid Spiff</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                @for (int date = 0; date < Model.Count; date ++)
                {
                    <tr class="date-row" onclick="$('.date_@date').toggleClass('date-hide');">
                        <td class="spiffdate">
                            @Model[date].Date.ToString("dddd MM/dd/yyyy")
                            <i class="fa fa-plus-circle expander_open" ></i>
                        </td>
                        <td>@Model[date].Carriers.Sum(c => c.SubmittedActivationCount) / @Model[date].Carriers.Sum(c => c.PotentialSpiffTotal).ToString("C")</td>

                        <td>@Model[date].Carriers.Sum(c => c.EligibleActivationCount) / @Model[date].Carriers.Sum(c => c.ApprovedSpiffTotal).ToString("C")</td>

                        <td>@Model[date].Carriers.Sum(c => c.IneligibleActivationCount) / @Model[date].Carriers.Sum(c => c.UnpaidSpiffTotal).ToString("C")</td>
                    </tr>

                    for (int carrier = 0; carrier < Model[date].Carriers.Count; carrier++)
                    {
                        <tr class="date_@date date-hide" onclick="$('.submitted-@date-@carrier').toggleClass('carrier-hide');">
                            <td><span class="pull-left dash"><i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i></span> @Model[date].Carriers[carrier].Carrier</td>
                            <td>
                                <a onclick="pullDetails('@Model[date].Carriers[carrier].CarrierId', '@Model[date].Date', 'potential' ,'submitted-@date-@carrier')">
                                    @(Model[date].Carriers[carrier].SubmittedActivationCount == 0 ? "--" :
                                    Model[date].Carriers[carrier].SubmittedActivationCount + " / " +
                                    Model[date].Carriers[carrier].PotentialSpiffTotal.ToString("C"))
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a onclick="pullDetails('@Model[date].Carriers[carrier].CarrierId', '@Model[date].Date', 'eligible' ,'submitted-@date-@carrier')">
                                    @(Model[date].Carriers[carrier].EligibleActivationCount == 0 ? "--" :
                                    Model[date].Carriers[carrier].EligibleActivationCount + " / " +
                                    Model[date].Carriers[carrier].ApprovedSpiffTotal.ToString("C"))
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a onclick="pullDetails('@Model[date].Carriers[carrier].CarrierId', '@Model[date].Date', 'ineligible' ,'submitted-@date-@carrier')">
                                    @(Model[date].Carriers[carrier].IneligibleActivationCount == 0 ? "--" :
                                    Model[date].Carriers[carrier].IneligibleActivationCount + " / " +
                                    Model[date].Carriers[carrier].UnpaidSpiffTotal.ToString("C"))
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr class="date_@date date-hide submitted-@date-@carrier carrier-hide carrier">
                            <td class="submitted_details" colspan="100%">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('.date-row').click(function () {
        $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-minus-circle fa-plus-circle');
    });
});
$(function () {
    $('.date-hide').click(function () {
        $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-caret-down fa-caret-up');
    });
});

function pullDetails(carrierId, startDate, status, divid) {
    $.get("@Url.Action("getDelayedSpiffOrderDetails", "Dashboard")",
        { carrierId: carrierId, startDate: startDate, status: status },
        function (data) {
            $('.' + divid + ' .submitted_details').html(data);
            $('.' + divid).removeClass('carrier-hide');

        });        
}
```

Comment: "... before the data is pulled back"? Isn't the DOM normally updated *after* data are returned?

Comment: @isherwood the data come from an MVC controller.  I need the div where this data is loading to reload before it displays the data?  Is that clearer?  I really know nothing about javascript.  Thanks.

Comment: No, it isn't. Reload what?

Comment: @isherwood do you want me to post more of my code?  I can probably explain it a lot better but I would need to post a lot of code.

Comment: Whatever it takes. :-)

Comment: @isherwood ok give me a sec and I'll update my question.

Comment: What object do you really want to reload... the DIV or the TABLE inside it??

Comment: Maybe you mean that you want to hide or show the div. That's different than loading or populating it.

Comment: What I need to to do is reload the data when a date is picked from the datepicker and passed to the controller on button click

Comment: just trigger the function pullDetails() whenever the date changes on the datepicker

Comment: @mCube how do I do that?  the datepicker is in a different view.  the pullDetails function is inside of a different view.

Comment: just bind a change() event to you datepicker and from there call the pullDetails() function that you created.

Comment: @mCube would you want to post an answer with some code in it?  I really don't know javascript.

Comment: what is the css class or id of your datepicker?

Comment: @mCube the id of the datepicker is startDate

Comment: @mCube I added the code for the view that loads inside the tabpanel to my question.  maybe this will make more sense?

Comment: try the answer that I posted. Im not sure how to call your function pullDetails() properly but that might guide you. Also, you can put the function call inside the $('.date-hide').click(function () that you posted.

Comment: @mCube ok I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
$("#startDate").change(function () {
// call your function here
});
```

Comment: I'm not really sure which view to put it in?  Does it matter?